# mysql SELECT by index return wrong selection

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have table as follows:

[image]

When i do:

```
SELECT * FROM userslogin WHERE userid='2'
```

It return the correct row but when i do:

```
SELECT * FROM userslogin WHERE userid='2**x**'
```

It also returns the same row. Same for:

```
SELECT * FROM userslogin WHERE userid='**2abc**'
```

What is the correct query to return a row for userid='2' only?

Comment: select * from userslogin where userid=2

Comment: As @RadimBača said... `userid` is int and you provide a string value so it all depends on how mysql converts that to int.

Comment: This is a common question on mysql. Mysql attempts an implicit conversion from string to integer because that's what id is defined as and stops at the first non integer character. In effect mysql is trying to do you a favour. The correct way to compare any 2 items is to use the same type - in this case int. And the 'feature' as nothing to do with the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are querying aginst an int you do not need the quotes.

```
 SELECT * FROM USERSLOGIN WHERE USERID = 2;
```